# combining two case queries into one

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to make a query where where i first check the current date with the date in a column and then base on that I am writing my case. this query is working fine individually but when 
i am combining them its not working.
The queires are

```
SELECT MONTH(CURRENT_DATE)= SUBSTRING(yearmonth,6) FROM dp;

SELECT i, 
CASE 
WHEN DAY(CURRENT_DATE) =1 THEN `d1_v` 
WHEN DAY(CURRENT_DATE) =2 THEN `d1_v` 
END VALUE 
FROM dp;
```

combined query..

```
SELECT i, 
CASE 
WHEN((MONTH(CURRENT_DATE ))= SUBSTRING(yearmonth,6) THEN 
(CASE
         WHEN DAY(CURRENT_DATE) = 1 THEN `d1_v`
            WHEN DAY(CURRENT_DATE) = 2 THEN `d1_v`
         END VALUE)END)Y
                  FROM dp
```

please guide me

Comment: could you make a sqlfiddle for this?

Comment: what is your expected output ? can you explain it with records ?

Comment: Yes I suppose I've found a solution but wat is the expected output? And d1_v isn't there in you're fiddle!?

Comment: d1_v is the short name for daily1_value..I have justed changed each column name

Comment: Yes I already tested with that but what is the expected outcome? 5,null for you're input I hope???

Comment: What I want is if the month matches my current month then I want to compare the current day with the colunm having the day value and retrive the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've to delete the '(' after the THEN:

```
SELECT i, 
CASE 
WHEN ((MONTH(CURRENT_DATE )) = SUBSTRING(yearmonth,6))THEN 
  CASE
      WHEN DAY(CURRENT_DATE) = 1 THEN `day1_value`
      WHEN DAY(CURRENT_DATE) = 2 THEN `day1_value`
  END 
END Y
FROM dp;
```

The output from the sqlfiddle is 5,null right now.

Hope this work for you.
The sqlfiddle is: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e59c5/10